# Lambda function cannot PutItem in DynamoDB database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, identity-management

Although I have given the function IAM profile complete AdministratorAccess permissions, along with AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess permissions as well, every time that I test the function I am greeted with the same error message:

`no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action.`

How do I fix this? I literally cannot give the IAM profile more access, so I am very confused. I have given every permission I can give.

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548506/accessdeniedexception-while-trying-to-do-dynamodbputitem-action

Comment: Did you try to create a customized role PutItem and attach to the Lambda service account ?

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think on

1. Check you are assigning the policies to the Lambda Execution Role.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html
2. Are you part of an organization, check that you no not have any SCP policies in place preventing the PutItem as it would take precedence.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html